# In PixiJS, is it possible to have blend modes applied in a transparent render texture work with the layer behind?

Tags: pixi.js

If sprites are rendered into a transparent render texture with different blend modes and some are rendered against the transparent parts, they render black when on top of a background.

Is it possible to get blend modes to work against the background i.e something set as add or multiply inside the render texture will add or multiply with the background? I'd probably have to put each blend mode into its own render texture and set the whole render texture to use that blend mode.

Assuming it's not possible to have the blend modes work with a single render texture, is it possible to make the black parts transparent? Multiply or add against transparent renders black in a render texture by default.